# Help with the sub-groups for Organic groups module

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I want to have this functionality in my website, but I really do not know how to use this module, I tried to follow this tutorial http://mohitaghera.drupalgardens.com/content/creating-subgroup-organic-groups

But there is a step I do not understand, you have to set the sub-group content type a group or a group content in the og settings?

Please have someone used this module? how to use it. How does it work, what is the workflow of this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this post, it will help you to figure out how to use the sub-og module

https://www.drupal.org/node/1345212